# How would I separate the time observed from this column and create it as a new attribute?

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes

I'm using QGIS and I am working with a file in which there is a attribute "time_obser" that is written as yyyy/mm/dd time (ex:2019/07/13 19:47:45.000).  I would like to create a new field that has only the hour of the day observed (ex:19 from the previous example) so I could determine if the observations were taking place during the day or night.  How would I go about using the field calculator to create a new field to capture this information?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new field and enter the following expression into the field calculator expression editor:

```
right(regexp_substr("time_obser", '^(.+?):'),2)
```

The `regexp_substring()` function returns everything in the "time_obser" field before the ':' character, then the `right()` function extracts just the 2 right-most characters from that substring.

See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on layer > open attribute table > toggle editing mode > Open field calculator

Set output field name. Let say you set the field name "hour". Then enter the below formula and it should create a new field with hour value in the attribute table.

hour(to_datetime("time_obser"))

Output of : hour(to_datetime( '2019/07/13 19:47:45.000')) will be 19.